# Why doesn't Javascript change the background color of my div if there is nothing inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use CSS and Javascript to make a grid of squares that change color after you have moused over them.

[Here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/cCAJh/)

```
makeGrid(10);

$(".grid").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('color','lightgreen');
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
    }
);

//Create a grid n x n
function makeGrid(n){
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            $('.pad').append('<div class="grid">Thing</div>');
            //$('.pad').append('<div class="grid"></div>');
        }
    }


   }
```

And the css

```
.pad{
    background-color: black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    float: center;
}

.activated {
    background-color: white;
}
.grid{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

It seems like I was able to get it to work if the div contains something (like the first way shows) but doesn't work if there is nothing inside the div (like the commented out one shows). I have set the divs to have a size in the css and I see they still appear because of the different background color but the mouseover even no longer works even though I specify the actual div. Why does this not work? Am I missing something?

Comment: The code in the fiddle has nearly nothing in common with the code in the question.

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't even match the code you put here. It doesn't have a `.pad` element for your JavaScript to even initiate the grid.

Comment: Could you edit your fiddle to reflect what you are asking over here?

Comment: `color` property is for text color – if you want to change the _background_ color, as your question title says, then you should use the according CSS property.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9d9kbjk8/ - This shows empty `.grid` elements inside a `.pad` element that start out as black, turn to lightgreen on hover, then change to white on leaving....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to determine what you are asking. I presume the issue is that you are modifying the `color` attribute which is actually the font color and you want the `background-color` attribute like so:

```
$(".grid").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','lightgreen');
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    }
);
```